# Fixed positioned div moves to the side while scrolling the in FireFox, works fine in other browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, firefox

I have 2 pages on my site that have the same layout. Each page has a div in the right sidebar that with the help of jquery changes it's class when you scroll down the page.

I noticed a strange behavior on one of the pages in FF.

On this page http://bit.ly/QDhrz8 when I start to scroll down, div in right sidebar shifts to the right in Firefox only. Chrome and IE works as intended.

On the other page http://bit.ly/RLZ4ZK it works as it should without shifting to right on scroll div and it works the same way without issues in FireFox, Chrome, IE.

Both of the pages use the same layout, css and java code.

What causes the div to jump on this page http://bit.ly/QDhrz8 in Firefox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot say why this is happening, but I found out that you can get rid of the "jumping" effect by changing this line:

```
<td width="664" valign="top" class="content2">
```

to this:

```
<td valign="top" class="content2">
```

I believe that the width set in the html, somehow clashes with the `padding` - but I can't really say that it's the true reason, but at least the fix above seems to fix your issue in FF

Comment: It worked!! Will accept the answer in 7 mins when the site will allow me :) By the way maybe you'll figure why on this page http://bit.ly/S9eJ87 the div on the bottom of right sidebar on scroll down disappears in FF, yet it's visible in other browsers?

Comment: once you scroll down enough, in FF that div gets this class and style: `.bottom {bottom: 0; position: absolute;}` while in Chrome I see `.floater {position: fixed; top: 15px}` so the problem is in how the class is attached to that div, I guess