# Floated div jumps to the right in FireFox when position:fixed is added by jQuery, works fine in other browsers

Tags: jquery, html, firefox

I have essentially the same problem as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12984644/fixed-positioned-div-moves-to-the-side-while-scrolling-the-in-firefox-works-fin), except removing the fixed width only makes my problem worse. The problem can be seen on [this page](https://dev.ex.gl/legacycheer/about-us/the-leaders). The strange thing is I use the exact same code on the [blog page](https://dev.ex.gl/legacycheer/blog) and there is no problem on any browser.

I can try to post a fiddle if people want but it would be difficult to recreate the exact problem.

This is my JS:

```
if ($('.sticky-sidebar').length) {
    var sideBarTop = $('.sticky-sidebar').offset().top;
    stickySidebar = function() {
        if ($(window).width() >= 768) {
            $('.sticky-sidebar').css({
                width: 0.25*($('#container').width())
            });
            if ($(window).scrollTop() >= (sideBarTop - $('#header').outerHeight(true))) {
                $('.sticky-sidebar').css({
                    position: 'fixed',
                    top: $('#header').outerHeight(true)
                });
            } else {
                $('.sticky-sidebar').css({
                    position: '',
                    top: ''
                });
            }
        } else {
            $('.sticky-sidebar').css({
                width: $('#container').width()
            });
        }
    };
    stickySidebar();
    $(window).scroll(stickySidebar);
    $(window).on('resize', stickySidebar);
}
```

Comment: can you post a fiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with the following..

```
if ($('.sticky-sidebar').length) {
    var sideBarTop = $('.sticky-sidebar').offset().top;
    stickySidebar = function() {
        if ($(window).width() >= 768) {
            $('.sticky-sidebar').css({
                width: 0.25*($('#container').width())
            });
            if ($(window).scrollTop() >= (sideBarTop - $('#header').outerHeight(true))) {
                $('.sticky-sidebar').css({
                    position: 'fixed',
                    top: $('#header').outerHeight(true),
                    left : $("#content").offset().left
                });
            } else {
                $('.sticky-sidebar').css({
                    position: '',
                    top: ''
                });
            }
        } else {
            $('.sticky-sidebar').css({
                width: $('#container').width()
            });
        }
    };
    stickySidebar();
    $(window).scroll(stickySidebar);
    $(window).on('resize', stickySidebar);
}
```

added left to sticky-header

Comment: That did the trick! No idea why it worked on one page and not the other _without_ `left` though!